# Concatenating records in a single column without looping?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, mysql

I have a table with 1 column of varchar values.  I am looking for a way to concatenate those values into a single value without a loop, if possible.  If a loop is the most efficient way of going about this, then I'll go that way but figured I'd ask for other options before defaulting to that method.  I'd also like to keep this inside of a SQL query.

Ultimately, I want to do the opposite of a split function.

Is it possible to do without a loop (or cursor) or should I just use a loop to make this happen?

Edit:
Since there was a very good answer associated with how to do it in MySql (as opposed to MS Sql like I initially intended), I decided to retag so others may be able to find the answer as well.

Comment: +1 thanks for this. Maybe a simple concept, but very valuable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

declare @concat varchar(max)
set @concat = ''

select @concat = @concat + col1 + ','
from tablename1

Comment: you can't use an order by when using this method. you can using FOR XML PATH, like in my answer.  However FOR XML PATH is for SQL Server 2005 and up

Comment: @KM Thankfully I didn't need an order by clause in my case; however, it's good to know.

Comment: @KM.   If you do need an ORDER BY clause, you can SELECT TOP 100%, and SQL Server will allow it.

Comment: @curt, I tried this out (`ORDER BY ...`) on my SQL Server 2012 and I don't need the `TOP 100%` and it works. So, something must have changed since my comment in 2009...

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (Col1 int)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (30)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (400)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (12)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (46454)

SELECT
    STUFF(
             (
                  SELECT
                      ', ' + cast(Col1 as varchar(30))
                      FROM @YourTable
                      WHERE Col1<=400
                      ORDER BY Col1
                      FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, ''
         )
```

OUTPUT:

```
-------------------
1, 2, 12, 30, 400

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tackled a problem like this and looping took forever. So, I concantenated the values in the presentation medium (in this case Crystal Reports) and it was very fast.

Just an idea.

Comment: Sadly, the script I'm writing is pure data manipulation to correct some bad data.  If it was UI related I would agree that such would be a better choice of handling such.

Answer (score 1):

Probably dated now but check out [Adam Machanic's post on the topic](http://dataeducation.com/rowset-string-concatenation-which-method-is-best/).

And [this one is certainly dated; I wrote it in 2004](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-from-a-column-into-a-single-row.html).

Why do I prefer a function over "keeping it inside a SQL query"?  Because you'll probably have to do this more than once.  Why not encapsulate that code into a single module instead of repeating it all over the place?

Answer (score 1):

If it is MySQL, you can use GROUP_CONCAT

SELECT a, GROUP_CONCAT(b SEPARATOR ',') FROM table GROUP BY a;

Comment: FYI: Some will downvote you for providing an answer that's not relevant.

Comment: While I was looking for MS Sql, I'm still going to upvote it since someone else may inquire about this as well.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Fair enough.  Edited the question with a note about this answer and retagged to include mysql.