# SQL - Distinct on two columns and summarized values on third

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

I have a table with 3 different IDs. I want to distinct on column 1 and 2 and summarize the values of column 3 (into one field - maybe comma separated string). The summarized field doesn't have to "look nice" (no problems with: '4,3,' (comma at the end)).
I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.

E.g:

```
ID1  ID2  ID3
 1    1    5
 1    1    8
 1    2    5
 1    2    8
 2    3   10
 2    3   11
 2    5   12
```

SELECT ...?

The result:

```
ID1   ID2   Summary
 1     1      5,8
 1     2      5,8
 2     3      10,11
 2     5      12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit - removed trailing spaces in the third column**

Since you said the summarized field doesn't have to look nice, try this:

```
SELECT M1.ID1, M1.ID2,
(
    SELECT convert(nvarchar(50), ID3) + ',' 
    FROM MyTable M2
    WHERE M1.ID1 = M2.ID1 AND M1.ID2 = M2.ID2
    FOR XML PATH('')
) M1
FROM MyTable M1
GROUP BY M1.ID1, M1.ID2
```

It assumes your table name is called 'MyTable'.  This query results in commas at the end, but should get you started.  Using my test database, this was the output:

```
ID1 ID2  M1
1   1   5,8,
1   2   5,8,
2   3   10,11,
2   5   12,
```

If you want it cleaned up, this should work (although the query itself is ugly):

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, left(M1, len(M1) - 1) AS M1
FROM
(
    SELECT M1.ID1, M1.ID2,
    (
        SELECT convert(nvarchar(50), ID3) + ',' 
        FROM MyTable M2
        WHERE M1.ID1 = M2.ID1 AND M1.ID2 = M2.ID2
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) M1
    FROM MyTable M1
    GROUP BY M1.ID1, M1.ID2
) CleanedUp
```

Comment: +1 for group by +xml path, but you should look into STUFF() to cleanup the string, see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591325/concatenating-records-in-a-single-column-without-looping/1594824#1594824

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in aggregates in MSSQL that can achieve that. This [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) shows multiple ways of concatenating string values based on a group.

Answer (score 0):

I did that in Oracle but I think you can do the same in SQL Server

```
select id1, id2, testfunction(id1, id2)
from test 
group by  id1, id2;
```

The testfunction is defined as

```
create or replace function testfunction(v_id1 in number, v_id2 in number) return varchar2 is
  v_result varchar2(200);
  v_id3 number;

  cursor ids(p_id1 in number, p_id2 in number)  is 
   select id3 from test where id1 = p_id1 and id2 = p_id2;
begin
   open ids(v_id1, v_id2);
   loop
     fetch ids into v_id3;
     exit when ids%notfound;

     v_result := v_result || v_id3 || ',';
   end loop;
   close ids;

   return(v_result);
end testfunction;
```